# Заблокировали аккаунт Google Adwords без выяснения причин

Tags: google-adwords

Обращаюсь к ребятам, кто хорошо разбирается в Google Adwords!

Неделю назад создал аккаунт в Adwords, создал группу объявлений, добавил ключевые слова - реклама сайта по ремонту квартир.

Никаких ошибок не было, и все по правилам Adwords. Далее, когда все слова добавил и настроил рекламу, я пополнил баланс и меня заблокировали!
Вот что пишут:

```
Ваш аккаунт AdWords заблокирован, так как в нем зафиксированы серьезные или систематические нарушения правил размещения рекламы.
```

Обратился в службу поддержки в Чат - Объяснил всю ситуацию, мне написали, что они не видят никаких серьезных причин, и что нет никакого нарушения правил AdWords. Сказали подать на аппиляцию. Я подал на аппиляцию, далее через два дня написали мне на почту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Итог:** Мне никто из Поддержки AdWords не объяснил причину! А в чате, и когда им позвонил я второй раз, говорят, что не видят причину :D 
**Вопрос:** что мне делать? как добиться разблокировки, и где найти причину?))

Comment: Знакомый работает с ними , и как что когда его блокируют - это окончательно. Ему тоже никаких причин не объясняют, он арендует вдски и через них создаёт новые акки.

Comment: Крутые ребята в этом Adwords!

Comment: Это конечно очень пугает, поэтому нужно общаться с людьми, которые работают в этой сфере, и знают все "подводные камни" использования. Хотя это и есть, опыт.

Comment: У гугла сильно больная на голову команда `Adwords` и `PlayMarket`. Что там, что там анархия какая-то, а главное она не прекращается уже довольно давно. Решений лучше чем "Создавать новый акк, но не надеяться на то, что он долго проживёт" и "Заиметь там знакомых" ещё не придумали.

Comment: Возможно, Ваш сайт подпадал под запрещённую рекламу. Есть такие примеры запрещённой рекламы: создание и продвижение сайтов, предназначенных исключительно для показа рекламы, страниц, предназначенных исключительно для перенаправления пользователей на другие ресурсы. Либо у Вас контент не соответствовал заявленным ключевым словам или тексту. Или на сайте есть баннер, например, с алкоголем.

Comment: @Other, на создание нового акк не решаюсь пока) чтобы совсем не убрали меня из гугл :D  в письме написано, что не создавайте новые аккаунты, ибо они все будут заблокированы по тем же причинам (т.е. без причины).

Comment: Ну хуже чем "Вас забабанили и не собираемся восстанавливать" уже вряд ли будет, так что терять нечего!

Comment: @NewDevelop, сайт, который я хотел запустить в AdWords - абсолютно новый и 100% оптимизированный под SEO, никаких ошибок. Ранее запускал в Seopult.ru, там без проблем рекламировал сайт, но затрат было много, и возможности настроек очень ограничены, поэтому решил перейти на аккаунт в Google Adwords.